# React : I get an error when I use dropdown-menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with the fact I use `DropdownMenu` twice on the same page. How  can it be solved?
[image]

Comment: just use different ids for each of them

Comment: Warning: [react-bootstrap] The provided id 'nav-dropdown' was overwritten by the current navContext with 'left-tabs-example-tab-null'.

Comment: Try putting the code in a sandbox and give a link here so that people can resolve the issue sooner.